# Continuous random variable, positive part and probability of $P(X=0)$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

We all know that for a continuous random variable the probability of the variable taking a specific value is zero. However, I have come across the following example.

Consider a standard normal random variable $Z\sim {N}(0,1)$. This variable is surely continuous and $\mathbb{P}(Z=a)=0$ for every real number $a$. Furthermore, $\mathbb{P}(Z\leq 0)=0.5$.

Now define the variable $X = max(Z,0)$. Unlike $Z$ who has as range the whole real line, the image of $X$ are the positive reals (which nonetheless constitue an interval). Wikipedia states that if the range of a random variable is uncountably infinite (usually an interval) then
it is a continuous random variable. Hence, $X$ seems continuous to me. Also, the transformation $max(\cdot, 0)$ is continuous (though not differentiable at zero).

Why then

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(X=0) = \mathbb{P}(Z\leq 0) = 0.5?
\end{equation}

What am I missing here? Thank you for your help

Comment: Note that in the language of random variables, there is a difference between being "continuous" and "absolutely continuous".

Comment: $Z$ may be continuous but a continuous function of $Z$ may not be a continuous random variable.  The term continuous random variable only refers to a property of its distribution function. There is no notion of topological continuity of a random variable. A simple example: $X \sim N(0,1), f(x)=0$ for all $x$ and $Z=f(X)$.

Comment: What is the correct definition of a continuous random variable then? Based on Wikipedia's, $X$ seems to be continuous as its image is an interval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of example is classic. The easiest way to find what type of random variable it is is by graphing and finding what you need.  We have
$$
Y = max\{Z,0\} = \begin{cases}
0 & Z \leq 0 \\
Z & Z >0
\end{cases}
$$
the plot is

[image]

We can search for the accumulated. Note that the preliminary support of $y$ is $[0,\infty)$.

If $Y < 0$ we have $F_{Y}(y) = 0$. If $Y < y $, with $y >0$ we have
\begin{align*}
F_{Y}(y) & = P(Y \leq y) \\
& = P(Y < 0) + P(Y = 0) + P(Y \leq y) \\
& = 0 + P(Z \leq 0) + P(Z \leq y) \\
& = 1/2 + \Phi(y)
\end{align*}
To answer your question, look at what happens in $y =0$, it takes the value $0$, so it takes a point value.

The CDF is

[image]

And I think with this you can answer your questions. Question: Why is there a jump?

Comment: Thank you Daniel for you very detailed answer. If you don't mind, I would ask you some clarifications: (1) you mention the "accumulated"; is it a technical term that I don't know or you mean the cumulative distribution function? (2) what do you mean by a "point value"; a singleton? (3) Is Y a continuous random variable then, having an image which is an interval? If so, how can we reconcile with the statement that the probability at a single point of a continuous random variable is zero? Thank you

Comment: About your question, I can just say that the CDF of Y is discontinuous at zero. Searching further, I also found a seemingly different definition of continuous random variable: A continuous random variable is a random variable whose cumulative distribution function is continuous everywhere. Looking at this definition, I would say that Y is not a continuous random variable. Neither I would say that is a discrete random variable. What is it then?

Comment: $(1)$ yes haha, is the cumulative distribution function. $(2)$  is a value that the random variable takes. $(3)$ To recognize the interval I recommend you draw the function. In general, continuous functions always result in absolutely continuous random variables, but more exotic functions such as the maximum or minimum have specific values ​​as in this example.

Comment: If it is not absolutely continuous, and it is not discrete, then it is a mixed random variable. See https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter4/4_3_1_mixed.php#:~:text=Here%2C%20we%20will%20discuss%20mixed,part%20and%20a%20discrete%20part.